# Get all tables from all databases by a query

Tags: db2

I want to get a list of all the tables in all the DBs like: `db_name, table_name, card`

I tried `sysibm.tables`, `syscat.tables` & `sysibm.systables` but they all relevant to the current DB I'm connecting to..

what basically I'm looking for is equivalent to DBA_TABLES / CDB_TABLES in oracle..

Comment: Oracle's `DBA_TABLES` also lists only tables in the database you are connected to.

Comment: In 12c - `CDB_TABLES`, in 11G and below `DBA_TABLES`, the point is that you'll understand.

Comment: First question, where are the other databases?  Are they linked/federated in any way?

Comment: They are all under the same instance/user